# How to insert the average value in the middle of my existing ggplot2 lollipop chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using R in RStudio. I have the following set of R codes which produce lollipop charts from my dataframe:

```
library(tidyr) 
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(scales)

df2 <- read.csv("hotel_list.csv", as.is=TRUE, header = TRUE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

df3<-(subset(df2,Mth %in% c("Jan-20", "Feb-20", "Mar-20", "Apr-20", "May-20", "Jun-20")))

p1<-ggplot(df3,aes(x=Day, y=Rank)) + 
  geom_point(size=4, color="tomato3") + 
  geom_segment(aes(x=Day, 
                   xend=Day, 
                   y=0, 
                   yend=Rank)) + 
  #print value for each bar as well
  geom_text(color="purple", size=3, vjust=-1.0, 
            aes(label=sprintf("%0.0f", round(Rank, digits = 2))))+
  labs(title="Hotel Ranking (by Day and by Month)",
  subtitle="ABC Ltd") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(39, 65)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.7, color="tomato3")) +
  facet_wrap(~Mth, scales='free', ncol=3)

p1+ theme(strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(5,10,15,20,25,30)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=c(40), linetype="dotted", color = "red", size=1.2)
```

This is my output when running the codes above:

[image: Actual output]

I would like to calculate the monthly average of the Rank values and to overlay that average value in the middle of my existing lollipop charts (using a low opacity level).
Here is the expected output (screenshot shown only for the month of Feb-20):

[image: Expected output]

How can I achieve this?

Please find below a dput of dataframe df3:

```
structure(list(Hotel = c("ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", 
"ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd", "ABC Ltd"), Date = c("2020-01-01", 
"2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-06", 
"2020-01-07", "2020-01-08", "2020-01-09", "2020-01-10", "2020-01-11", 
"2020-01-12", "2020-01-13", "2020-01-14", "2020-01-15", "2020-01-16", 
"2020-01-17", "2020-01-18", "2020-01-19", "2020-01-20", "2020-01-21", 
"2020-01-22", "2020-01-23", "2020-01-24", "2020-01-25", "2020-01-26", 
"2020-01-27", "2020-01-28", "2020-01-29", "2020-01-30", "2020-01-31", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-02-02", "2020-02-03", "2020-02-04", "2020-02-05", 
"2020-02-06", "2020-02-07", "2020-02-08", "2020-02-09", "2020-02-10", 
"2020-02-11", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-13", "2020-02-14", "2020-02-15", 
"2020-02-16", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-20", 
"2020-02-21", "2020-02-22", "2020-02-23", "2020-02-24", "2020-02-25", 
"2020-02-26", "2020-02-27", "2020-02-28", "2020-02-29", "2020-03-01", 
"2020-03-02", "2020-03-03", "2020-03-04", "2020-03-05", "2020-03-06", 
"2020-03-07", "2020-03-08", "2020-03-09", "2020-03-10", "2020-03-11", 
"2020-03-12", "2020-03-13", "2020-03-14", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-16", 
"2020-03-17", "2020-03-18", "2020-03-19", "2020-03-20", "2020-03-21", 
"2020-03-22", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24", "2020-03-25", "2020-03-26", 
"2020-03-27", "2020-03-28", "2020-03-29", "2020-03-30", "2020-03-31", 
"2020-04-01", "2020-04-02", "2020-04-03", "2020-04-04", "2020-04-05", 
"2020-04-06", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-08", "2020-04-09", "2020-04-10", 
"2020-04-11", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", 
"2020-04-16", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-20", 
"2020-04-21", "2020-04-22", "2020-04-23", "2020-04-24", "2020-04-25", 
"2020-04-26", "2020-04-27", "2020-04-28", "2020-04-29", "2020-04-30", 
"2020-05-01", "2020-05-02", "2020-05-03", "2020-05-04", "2020-05-05", 
"2020-05-06", "2020-05-07", "2020-05-08", "2020-05-09", "2020-05-10", 
"2020-05-11", "2020-05-12", "2020-05-13", "2020-05-14", "2020-05-15", 
"2020-05-16", "2020-05-17", "2020-05-18", "2020-05-19", "2020-05-20", 
"2020-05-21", "2020-05-22", "2020-05-23", "2020-05-24", "2020-05-25", 
"2020-05-26", "2020-05-27", "2020-05-28", "2020-05-29", "2020-05-30", 
"2020-05-31", "2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", "2020-06-04", 
"2020-06-05", "2020-06-06", "2020-06-07", "2020-06-08", "2020-06-09", 
"2020-06-10", "2020-06-11", "2020-06-12", "2020-06-13", "2020-06-14", 
"2020-06-15", "2020-06-16", "2020-06-17", "2020-06-18", "2020-06-19", 
"2020-06-20", "2020-06-21", "2020-06-22", "2020-06-23", "2020-06-24", 
"2020-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-27", "2020-06-28", "2020-06-29", 
"2020-06-30"), Day = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L), Mth = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Jan-20", "Feb-20", "Mar-20", 
"Apr-20", "May-20", "Jun-20"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
    Rank = c(59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 59L, 61L, 
    61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L, 63L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 
    62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 62L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 
    61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 
    61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 
    61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 
    59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
    60L, 60L, 60L, 60L)), row.names = c(NA, 182L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: [mcve] please ?

Comment: Yeah, some data would be nice. Is the examplary graph with the opaque "61" what you already achieved and the problem is only to get this to the facetted case?

Comment: @BenBolker I have already provided the data in my question.

Comment: @mabreitling I have already provided the data in my question. The example graph has been edited in a graphics software for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually find it easier to create a separate little data frame to help:

```r
df4 <- df3 %>% 
  group_by(Hotel, Mth) %>% 
  summarise(Rank = sprintf("%0.0f", round(mean(Rank), digits = 2)), Day = 15)
```

Which allows us to slot in an extra `geom_text` call easily:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x = Day, y = Rank)) + 
        geom_point(size = 4, color="tomato3") + 
        geom_segment(aes(xend = Day, y = 0, yend = Rank)) +
        geom_text(color = "purple", size = 3, vjust = -1.0, 
                  aes(label = sprintf("%0.0f", round(Rank, digits = 2)))) +
        geom_text(aes(label = Rank, y = 50), data = df4, check_overlap = TRUE,
                  size = 30, colour = "gray50", alpha = 0.3) +
        labs(title = "Hotel Ranking (by Day and by Month)",
             subtitle = "ABC Ltd") + 
        coord_cartesian(ylim = c(39, 65)) +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.7, color = "tomato3")) +
        facet_wrap(~Mth, scales = 'free', ncol = 3)
```

Giving you your desired result:

```
p1 + 
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format()) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 40, linetype = "dotted", color = "red", size = 1.2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The final output is what I'm looking for. However, is it possible to compute the average using the mean of all the daily values instead of taking Day 15 as the average?

Comment: For example, I need the average of Jan-20 to be 61 (instead of 59) and Mar-20 would be 60 (instead of 61).

Comment: @user3115933 sorry - I forgot to `mean` the `Rank` when creating `df4`. See my update